# Django function working but I get error: Int object has no attribute _meta

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

My function works. I can see the added results returned, but i get an error:

> int object has no attribute _meta.

It seems i can't even save my HttpResponse.

TraceBack:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/swimmers-update/4

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\PJ\Fa's Salon\facms_python\accounts\views.py", line 404, in swimmersUpdate
    serializer.save()
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 207, in save
    self.instance = self.update(self.instance, validated_data)
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 993, in update
    info = model_meta.get_field_info(instance)
  File "C:\Users\CR\Envs\fcms\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\model_meta.py", line 35, in get_field_info
    opts = model._meta.concrete_model._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at /swimmers-update/4
Exception Value: 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def swimmersUpdate(request, pk):
    sw = get_object_or_404(Swimmers,id=pk).sessions

    current_sessions = sw + 10
    
    
    serializer = SubSerializer(instance=current_sessions, data=request.data)


    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return JsonResponse(data=serializer.errors, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Could you add the complete Stack Trace ? It would help pin point the cause of the exception.

Comment: What does SubSerializer do? You are passing an integer of `current_sessions` when it it likely expecting the `sw` object.

Comment: duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71911917/django-how-to-do-arithmetic-operations-in-django-rest-post-method

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an instance of an integer to the Subserializer but I suspect you want to be passing an instance of Swimmers.

Without knowing the fuller context, can you try:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def swimmersUpdate(request, pk):
    sw = get_object_or_404(Swimmers,id=pk)  # gets just one record

    current_sessions = sw.sessions + 10
    sw.sessions = current_sessions  # updates just the one in memory field for sw (for the one record)
    sw.save()  # you may want to do this to commit the new value
    serializer = SubSerializer(instance=sw, data=request.data)
    
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return JsonResponse(data=serializer.errors, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

### EDIT

I'm not up to date on the DRF's serializers, but I'd assume you may want to look at something more along the lines of the following (apologies in advance if the DRF serializers don't work this way):

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def swimmersUpdate(request, pk):
    sw = get_object_or_404(Swimmers,id=pk)  # gets just one record
    serializer = SubSerializer(instance=sw, data=request.data)   

    if serializer.is_valid():
        current_sessions = serializer.sessions
        serializer.sessions = current_sessions + 10  
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return JsonResponse(data=serializer.errors, safe=False, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: is the instanse is set to (sw) in updates the full model while i would like to update a field of name (sessions an IntegerField) and add + 10 to the value.

Comment: right. Django ORM uses the active record implementation, so `sw` becomes the 'row' of Swimmers with id=pk. You then set the field `sessions` to sessions+10. You could call `sw.save()` if you need to before your `SubSerializer` call. Post your `Swimmers` model code for more clarity.

Comment: It may help your mental idea of it to rename your `Swimmers` model in the singular `Swimmer`

Comment: Thank You it solved the problem, how can i make it that whenever the functions runs it display as a record in a table.

Comment: displays where? I'm not sure what it is you are trying to achieve. For me, I think about if it made more sense to move the increment of 10 inside the `is_valid` check. It depends on what SubSerializer is doing and what its purpose is.